# What is the orthogonal complement of three linearly independent vectors in the 3-dimensional space?

Tags: linear-algebra

If I have 3 linearly independent vectors, assume the standard basis, in R3, what would be its orthogonal complement? Would there even be one. Isn't the entire space represented by the standard basis?

Answer (score 1):

Those three linear independent vectors span $\mathbb{R}^3$, and the orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would any of the standard basis in the 4-dimensional space be an orthogonal complement to linearly independent vectors in R3 as well? Or are orthogonal complements limited in the subspace of the linearly indepent vectors?

Comment: I believe it is about subspaces only.

Comment: Sounds good. Cheers.

Comment: If you embed $\mathbf R^3$ in  $\mathbf R^4$ by some isometry, then your three independent vectors have independent images, and it ùmakes sense to speak of their orthgonal complement in  $\mathbf R^4$. The notion of orthogonal complement is always relative to some sourrounding space.